# C++ Template Meta Programming: Inheritance from template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, policy, policy-based-design

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename is_allocated>
struct mutable_storage {};

template <
    template<typename, typename, typename> class storage_t,
    typename T2           = void,
    typename is_allocated = std::false_type
>
class Buffer : storage_t<Buffer<storage_t,void,void>, T2, is_allocated>
{};



int main() {
    typedef Buffer<mutable_storage> example_buffer;
}
```

This code compiles (at least using the GNU GCC Compiler following C++14). However, I dislike the used syntax

```
class Buffer : storage_t<Buffer<storage_t,void,void>, T2, is_allocated>
```

due to the fact it shouldn't require the Buffer to be specialized: I would like Buffer to be recognized as a template template parameter, like:

```
class Buffer : storage_t<Buffer, T2, is_allocated>
```

Then I would like the mutable_storage struct to recognize a template specialization like

```
template <typename T2, typename is_allocated>
struct mutable_storage<Buffer, T2, is_allocated> { ... };
```

(Would of course not be allowed, as "Buffer" is not a type, so that should be changed too).
But the way it uses right now, being  able to specialize with type 
Buffer feels a bit nasty. Using a typedef, for example

```
 typedef Buffer<storage_t, void, void> Buffer_Policy
```

also feels a bit nasty. I'm  looking for a cleaner way. I've tried to make a template template template parameter, but that leads to an infinite flow of extra templates within the template parameter (I don't know exactly how template<...> works, so maybe that?), as the Buffer inherits from something that requires another Buffer in order to declare storage_t. I've also tried using a implicit class, namely inner_storage_t. Neither did this lead to a success. Does anyone have suggestions in order to make the program cleaner? By the way, if you see any other mistakes or inefficiencies, feel free to mention it. Thanks for reading and possibly your help.

Comment: This indeed looks generally awkward. It's a little hard to propose alternatives without knowing what the storage types are expected to do with the T1 parameter. Could you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: Thanks a lot for reacting! It is actually only meant for template specialization, in order to define how to type T1 be stored. I found out that I had made a slight mistake creating this post, which I will edit now, but for specialization: template<T1, T2> struct mutable_storage<Buffer, T1, T2> should be template<T2, is_allocated> struct mutable_storage<Buffer, T2, is_allocated>. I'm sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `T1` is only meant to be used for template specialization selection, you don't really have to use `Buffer` itself. You can use a tag type instead.

Squirreling it away in a namespace also allows you to avoid polluting the rest of the enclosing namespace with the tags.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename is_allocated>
struct mutable_storage {};

namespace storage_tags {
  struct Buffer_T {};
}

template <
    template<typename, typename, typename> class storage_t,
    typename T2           = void,
    typename is_allocated = std::false_type
>
class Buffer : public storage_t<storage_tags::Buffer_T, T2, is_allocated> { 

};
```